# Android - Network usage with google maps api

Tags: android, networking, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm not really familiar with android or data plan stuff in general, so I was wondering if doing things like using google maps api or admod would result in using up users data plans.

Also, if it does, a few more questions.

1. Do I have to put a warning or something?
2. How much data would this use?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

of course it uses data, where do you think all the map tiles and ads come from?

with the `Internet` permissions that you have to give, the user expects there to be data used so you dont have to do anything

Comment: Thank you, I knew it was data, I just just have no idea about the whole data plan thing. And never released an app.